# R - Object not found in user-defined function

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

So I've seen this question asked multiple times before, but none of the other answers I've tried seem to work. When I run the below function, I get: "Error: object 'x' not found."

```
xpermntotable <- function(x,y,z){
  xmovematrix <- matrix(unlist(xpermn), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
  for(i in 1:120){
    xmove1 <- xmovematrix[i,1]
    xmove2 <- xmovematrix[i,2]
    xmove3 <- xmovematrix[i,3]
    print(x)
    xtemp <- filter_(fullTable, .dots=list(
      bquote(.(as.name(xmove1)) == x), 
      bquote(.(as.name(xmove2)) == y), 
      bquote(.(as.name(xmove3)) == z)))
    xwin <- rbind(xwin, xtemp)
  }
}

xpermntotable(1,2,3)
```

The problem seems to be rooted in the specific part of the function below, where the "x" (and presumably the "y" and "z") are not being read properly:

```
xtemp <- filter_(fullTable, .dots=list(
          bquote(.(as.name(xmove1)) == x), 
          bquote(.(as.name(xmove2)) == y), 
          bquote(.(as.name(xmove3)) == z)))
```

**Solutions I have tried:**

- Containing the "x" variable in as.name(x), or eval(x)

Answer (score 0):

So after more digging into the bquote function, I realised that my solution was there all along. The x, y, and z variables needed to be wrapped with

```
.()
```

The below code works:

```
xpermntotable <- function(x,y,z){
  xmovematrix <- matrix(unlist(xpermn), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
  for(i in 1:120){
    xmove1 <- xmovematrix[i,1]
    xmove2 <- xmovematrix[i,2]
    xmove3 <- xmovematrix[i,3]
    xtemp <- filter_(fullTable, .dots=list(
      bquote(.(as.name(xmove1)) == .(x)), 
      bquote(.(as.name(xmove2)) == .(y)), 
      bquote(.(as.name(xmove3)) == .(z))))
    xwin <- rbind(xwin, xtemp)
    return(xwin)
  }
}


xwin <- xpermntotable(1,2,3)
```

More information on the bquote function [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bquote.html).

Comment: Right. You didn't read the manual. I don't think this is anything more than a typo yopu have now corrected.